# How to use the introspect endpoint of fusionauth?

Tags: fusionauth

I am trying to use the introspect endpoint of fusionauth with a REST client. When making the request, 
it returns the code 405 with the following message:

code 405
The request method is known by the server but has been disabled and cannot be used

Is this endpoint disabled or do you have to configure it in the fusionauth ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FusionAuth [Introspect endpoint](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/oauth/endpoints#introspect) should be made using a `POST` request. If you are receiving a `405` my guess is that you're using the `GET` HTTP method.

For reference, here is the [Introspect RFC 7662 section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.1).

> The protected resource calls the introspection endpoint using an HTTP
> POST [RFC7231] request with parameters sent as
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" data as defined in
> [W3C.REC-html5-20141028].

If that isn't the case, can you post an example request?